# Changing Default folder in C#

Tags: c#, path, directory, default

I am trying to create a console application that allows users to access some properties of files and folders such as name, sizes etc. This is an assignment, so to get bonus marks I have to change the default folder to user specified folder ONLY if the user selects the option to do so. The issue here is, in the

```
if else (userSelection == 2) // code to allow users to change folder path
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Enter the Path of the Folder you wish to keep as default");
         userChoiceFolder = Console.ReadLine();

         if (Directory.Exists(userChoiceFolder))
         {
             Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(userChoiceFolder);
             Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
         }
    }
```

if else statement above, it does change the folder, but only while within the if else scope.
What I am trying to do is to change the default path in

```
DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
```

to what the user specifies in the if else selection 2 statement. So what the user specifies replaces "C:\"). This is the full code

```
        DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
        FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();
        int userSelection;
        string userInput;
        string userChoiceFolder;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome! Please make a selection by Entering 1, 2, 2 or 4");
        DisplayMenuOptions();
        bool isUserSelection = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userSelection);

        while (isUserSelection == false || userSelection >= 1 && userSelection <= 5)
        {
            if (userSelection == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Files in C/: {0}", folderInfo.Name);

                for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
                {
                    //Code for file info
                }
            }
            else if (userSelection == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Path of the Folder you wish to keep as default");
                userChoiceFolder = Console.ReadLine();

                if (Directory.Exists(userChoiceFolder))
                {
                    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(userChoiceFolder);
                    Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                }
            }
            else if (userSelection == 3)
            {
                //Code for filtered file listing
                for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < fileType.Length; fIndex++)
                {
                    //Filetered fie listing display
                }
            }
            else if (userSelection == 4)
            {
                //File statitstics code
            }
            else if (userSelection == 5)
            {
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, to make a selection you must enter 1, 2, 3 or 4");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            DisplayMenuOptions();
            bool isSelection = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userSelection);

        }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(userChoiceFolder);
```

you should also set `folderInfo` to use this new value. Otherwise, `folderInfo` will continue to provide info only about the C:\ folder set initially.

Also, since `files = folderInfo.GetFiles()` is set based on the folderInfo, you would need to set this also. It would be better to move these 2 lines into a separate method instead.

Comment: @susheeshix I am trying to do that but it comes up with an error instead

Comment: How are you trying to change the value? You'll need to use the new constructor to build new object the way you built the first one.

Comment: @sudheeshix may be I am doing it wrong, it is like this folderInfo = Directory.SetDirectory(userChoiceFolder);

Comment: @BenKnoble I tried that but it doesnt apply to the overall program, it like whatever happens in the block stays in the block... also I am a beginner so thats why I am struggling with this

Comment: Look at the return type of SetCurrentDirectory. It is void. So, you cannot use that to reset `folderInfo`.
Use `userChoiceFolder` to set it again.
`folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(userChoiceFolder);`

Comment: you need two lines: `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(userChoiceFolder)` and `folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(userChoiceFolder);` @sudheesix may have the right idea: create a changeDir(String path) method that will take care of editing the appropriate vars

Comment: Thank you :) I still do not understand the change dir concept, but I am trying :)

Comment: Thank You SO MUCH!!! It works!!! I can get the bonus point now :) Don't worry I will be referencing this in my project

Comment: Ok :) I guess you should also read this to understand the concept of the current/present working directory:
`When the process refers to a file using a simple file name or relative path (as opposed to a file designated by a full path from a root directory), the reference is interpreted relative to the current working directory of the process.`
from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

Comment: @sudheeshix :) Thank you once again :)